# Powershell Rename dynamic filenames containing square brackets, from the filetype scans in the directory

Tags: regex, powershell, pattern-matching, regex-group, rename-item-cmdlet

I don't much know(in details and specifics) about Powershell's silly and ridiculous issues/bugs in handling square brackets(just because it escapes strings multiple times internally) in the path strings, where I have to use Regex with asterisk(*) to match/catch the patterns.

I did heavy Googling and found that there's method `[WildcardPattern]::Escape($Filename)` that could help me `Rename-Item` such dynamic file paths, I thought the below code would work with such dynamic paths which are result of file-type scans in the current folder, but disappointingly, it doesn't:

```
Set-Location "$PSScriptRoot"
$MkvFiles = Get-ChildItem -Filter *.mkv -Path $Path
Foreach ($MkvFile in $MkvFiles) {
    $MkvOrigName = [WildcardPattern]::Escape($MkvFile.Name)
    $MkvOrigFullname = [WildcardPattern]::Escape($MkvFile.FullName)
    If ($MkvOrigName -Match '.*(S[0-9]{2}E[0-9]{2}).*') {
        $NewNameNoExt = $MkvOrigFullname -Replace '.*(S[0-9]{2}E[0-9]{2}).*', '$1'
        $NewName = "$NewNameNoExt.mkv"
        Rename-Item $MkvOrigFullname -NewName $NewName
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error with `Rename-Item` command when I run the above script on the folder that contains the files such as given at the end of question:

```
Rename-Item : An object at the specified path C:\Users\Username\Downloads\WebseriesName Season 
4\WebSeriesName.2016.S04E13.iNTERNAL.480p.x264-mSD`[eztv`].mkv does not exist.
At C:\Users\Username\Downloads\WebseriesName Season 4\BulkFileRenamerFinalv1.ps1:12 char:9
+         Rename-Item $MkvOrigFullname -NewName $NewName
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The Webseries file paths in the current folder, that I am dealing with are like these:

```
WebSeriesName.2016.S04E01.HDTV.x264-SVA[eztv].mkv
WebSeriesName.2016.S04E02.HDTV.x264-SVA[eztv].mkv
....
....
WebSeriesName.2016.S04E12.iNTERNAL.480p.x264-mSD[eztv].mkv
WebSeriesName.2016.S04E13.iNTERNAL.480p.x264-mSD[eztv].mkv
```

Someone could help me figuring out this problem generically without need to headbang with what the filenames strings contain, as long as they contain the string like `S04E01`,`S04E02` etc. and surely contain square brackets ? That is, how can I escape the square brackets and rename them, as apparent in the code afore-mentioned, to the names given below ?

```
S04E01.mkv
S04E02.mkv
....
....
S04E12.mkv
S04E13.mkv
```

Comment: Just use `-literalpath` in `rename-item` and no escaping will be necessary. By not naming a path parameter, `-path` binds to the position 0 argument, which does interpret wildcards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the pipeline, you don't need to worry about escaping paths. This is because `PSPath` property will automatically bind to the `-LiteralPath` parameter on [Rename-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-7).

```
Set-Location "$PSScriptRoot"
$MkvFiles = Get-ChildItem -Filter *.mkv -Path $Path
Foreach ($MkvFile in $MkvFiles) {
    If ($MkvFile.Name -Match '.*(S[0-9]{2}E[0-9]{2}).*') {
        $MkvFile | Rename-Item -NewName {"{0}{1}" -f $matches.1,$_.Extension}
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

The `-NewName` parameter supports [delay-bind scripting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7). So we can use a script block to do the property/string manipulation.

If wildcards are not needed for the path query, then using `-LiteralPath` is the best approach. The `-LiteralPath` value is bound exactly as typed (literal/verbatim string). `-Path` for `Get-ChildItem` accepts wildcards, but `-Path` for `Rename-Item` does not support wildcards. Yet it seems like PowerShell still cares when parsing the command. If you must escape some wildcard characters in a `-Path` parameter that accepts wildcards, then double quoted paths require 4 backticks and single quoted paths require 2 backticks. This is because two levels of escape are required.

When using `-match` against a single string even if in a conditional statement, the `$matches` automatic variable is updated when a match is successful. Capture group matches are accessed using syntax `$matches.capturegroupname` or `$matches[capturegroupname]`. Since you did not name the capture group, it was automatically named `1` by the system. A second set of `()` around a capturing group, would have been `2`. It is important to remember that when `-match` is `False`, `$matches` is not updated from its previous value.

---

**Examples of handling wildcard characters in `-Path` parameters that support wildcards:**

`````
# Using double quotes in the path
$Path = "WebSeriesName.2016.S04E01.HDTV.x264-SVA````[eztv].mkv"
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path

# Using single quotes in the path
$Path = "WebSeriesName.2016.S04E01.HDTV.x264-SVA``[eztv].mkv"
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path

# Using LiteralPath
$Path = "WebSeriesName.2016.S04E01.HDTV.x264-SVA[eztv].mkv"
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $Path
Rename-Item -LiteralPath $Path -NewName 'MyNewName.mkv'

# Using WildcardPattern Escape method
$Path = 'WebSeriesName.2016.S04E01.HDTV.x264-SVA[eztv].mkv'
$EscapedPath = ([WildcardPattern]::Escape([WildcardPattern]::escape($path)))
Get-ChildItem -Path $EscapedPath
`````